# Optimizing __getitem__ for a bioinformatics script in Python

Tags: python, optimization, bioinformatics

I'm writing a script for a bioinformatics application in Python that iterates through several sequences looking for amino acids in specific positions to calculate their frequency in relation to a genomic database. However, I'm new to the area and I've been learning while developing the project, so a lot of what I've done is poorly optimized. For a task that I consider relatively simple, the script takes half a minute for files and sometimes much longer for larger files

Can anyone suggest how I might try to get around this problem? Apologies if it's trivial, I'm a biologist just starting to get to grips with programming

```
def main(self):
    # Process input data and extract necessary information
    mutation_count, mutation_subjects, mutation_positions, alignment_file, seq_ID = self.process_input()

    # Initialize a dictionary to count amino acids at each mutation position
    aa_counts = {pos: {} for pos in mutation_positions}

    # Read the alignment file using Bio.AlignIO
    alignment = AlignIO.read(alignment_file, 'clustal')
    
    # Find the reference sequence in the alignment
    ref_seq = None
    for record in alignment:
        if record.id == seq_ID:
            ref_seq = record
            break

    # Convert sequences in the alignment to strings for easier processing
    ref_seq_str = str(ref_seq.seq)
    alignment_str = {record.id: str(record.seq) for record in alignment}

    # Count amino acids at each position in the alignment
    for seq in alignment_str.values():
        pos_in_ref_seq = 0
        for pos, aa in enumerate(seq):
            if ref_seq_str[pos] != '-':
                pos_in_ref_seq += 1

            if pos_in_ref_seq in aa_counts:
                aa_counts[pos_in_ref_seq][aa] = aa_counts[pos_in_ref_seq].get(aa, 0) + 1
                    
    # If a specific position is provided, calculate and print the amino acid frequencies at that position
    if self.args.position:
        position = self.args.position
        total_count = sum(aa_counts[position].values())
        for aa, count in aa_counts[position].items():
            freq = (count / total_count * 100) if total_count > 0 else 0
            print(f"Amino Acid: {aa} | Frequency: {freq:.2f}% | Count: {count}")
        return
                
    # Analyze mutations and calculate frequencies
    mutation_info = {}
    for mutation, count in sorted(mutation_count.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:-1])):
        seq_pos = int(mutation[1:-1])
        query_aa = mutation[0]
        subject_aa = mutation[-1]
        
        if query_aa == '-' or subject_aa == '-':
            continue
        
        real_count = aa_counts[seq_pos].get(subject_aa, 0)
        total_count = sum(aa_counts[seq_pos].values())
        query_aa_frequency = (aa_counts[seq_pos].get(query_aa, 0) / total_count * 100) if total_count > 0 else 0
        subject_aa_frequency = (aa_counts[seq_pos].get(subject_aa, 0) / total_count * 100) if total_count > 0 else 0
        
        if subject_aa_frequency <= 10 and real_count > 2:
            mutation_info[mutation] = {
                'query_aa_frequency': query_aa_frequency,
                'subject_aa_frequency': subject_aa_frequency,
                'real_count': real_count,
            }
    
    # Identify strains with specific mutations
    strains_with_mutations = {}
    for mutation in mutation_count:
        query_aa, pos, subject_aa = mutation[0], int(mutation[1:-1]), mutation[-1]
        strains_with_this_mutation = []

        for record in alignment:
            strain_name = record.id[:3] 
            sequence = str(record.seq)
            
            pos_in_ref_seq = 0
            
            for i, aa in enumerate(sequence):
                if ref_seq.seq[i] != '-':
                    pos_in_ref_seq += 1
                
                if pos_in_ref_seq == pos:
                    
                    if aa == subject_aa:
                        strains_with_this_mutation.append(strain_name[:3])
                    break  
        strains_with_mutations[mutation] = strains_with_this_mutation
            
    # Write mutation information to a text file
    with open('gapslist.txt', 'w') as f:
        for mutation, info in mutation_info.items():
            f.write(f"Mutation: {mutation} | {mutation[0]} Frequency: {info['query_aa_frequency']:.2f}% | {mutation[-1]} Frequency: {info['subject_aa_frequency']:.2f}% | Count: {info['real_count']}\n\n")

    # Write mutation and strain information to a CSV file
    with open('rare_mutations.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Mutation', 'Strains']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        
        for mutation, info in mutation_info.items():
            writer.writerow({
                'Mutation': mutation,
                'Strains': ';'.join(strains_with_mutations.get(mutation, []))
            })
```

Profiling the code, I realized that the biggest bottleneck is the number of times the _*getitem*_ function of the Seq class in Bio.Seq is being called:

```
  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

 69006091  25.002  0.000     99.135   0.000   Seq.py:470(__getitem__)

 69098925  6.311   0.000     6.311    0.000   SeqRecord.py:334(<lambda>).

 69008225  10.165  0.000     49.965   0.000   <frozen abc>:117(__instancecheck__)

 69006091  10.330  0.000     22.310   0.000   <frozen abc>:121(__subclasscheck__)
```

I've been looking into ways of dealing with this but nothing seems to be working, or it's only marginally reducing execution time.

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `aa_counts[seq_pos]` could be assigned to some other variable and used all through your following code for instance. You'll save a lot of lookups.

Comment: same here: `if pos_in_ref_seq in aa_counts:
                aa_counts[pos_in_ref_seq][aa] = aa_counts[pos_in_ref_seq].get(aa, 0) + 1` for `aa_counts[pos_in_ref_seq]`, but woodford is right, codereview would be a better place for this, I can perform the migration BTW

Comment: the last part Identify strains with specific mutations seems to have a O(n**4) loop with linear searches too

Comment: Please edit the question and post [mcve] with a **short** example of the input and output. Add `import` statements to enable other to run it. Perhaps mention how to install biopython, For example: To use [Biopython](https://biopython.org/), specifically [`Bio.SeqIO`](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO), it can be easily installed, for example using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'll be posting in Code Review then, and I'll also try your suggestions.

Comment: The Seq object essentially combines a Python string with biological methods.  https://biopython.org/wiki/Seq , do you really need to convert them in strings ??

Comment: see if this one is faster https://stackoverflow.com/a/73851435/9877065

Comment: see if this one is faster https://stackoverflow.com/a/73851435/9877065

Comment: The migrated question is here: [performance - Optimizing \_\_getitem\_\_ for a bioinformatics script in Python - Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288136/optimizing-getitem-for-a-bioinformatics-script-in-python)

Comment: You could try to monkey patch Seq.__getitem__ method at runtime with one that uses only indexes and not slices removing the if else clause present , see https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/5177f3504af450a4eac6bb467487747303a7c348/Bio/Seq.py#L470

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it right, I am trying to learn too.

I tried to modify `__getitem__` method as title suggest; method is here :

[github.com/biopython/Bio/Seq.py : 'class _SeqAbstractBaseClass(ABC) **getitem**'](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/5177f3504af450a4eac6bb467487747303a7c348/Bio/Seq.py#L470)

test code `test-001.py`:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq


a = 'MAGLVWT'

seq_a = Seq(a*1000000)

# print(seq_a , type(seq_a))

empty = { }

for i in a :
    
    empty[i] = 0
    
print(empty)

for i in range(len(seq_a)) :
    
    x = seq_a[i]
    
    empty[x] +=1
    
  
print(empty)
```

using cProfile :

```
> python -m cProfile -s cumulative  test-001.py 
{'M': 0, 'A': 0, 'G': 0, 'L': 0, 'V': 0, 'W': 0, 'T': 0}
<class 'Bio.Seq.Seq'>
{'M': 10000000, 'A': 10000000, 'G': 10000000, 'L': 10000000, 'V': 10000000, 'W': 10000000, 'T': 10000000}
         210037787 function calls (210037746 primitive calls) in 107.698 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      6/1    0.000    0.000  107.698  107.698 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1   48.584   48.584  107.698  107.698 test-001.py:3(<module>)
 70000000   40.908    0.000   59.003    0.000 Seq.py:410(__getitem__)
 70000033    9.140    0.000    9.140    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
 70000000    8.955    0.000    8.955    0.000 {built-in method builtins.chr}
.........
.......
......
.....
...
```

Patched code `test-002-patched-002.py` :

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq



def modded(self, index) :
    
    return chr(self._data[index])


Seq.__getitem__ = modded


a = 'MAGLVWT'

seq_a = Seq(a*10000000)

# print(seq_a , type(seq_a))


empty = { }

for i in a :
    
    empty[i] = 0
    
print(empty)

for i in range(len(seq_a)) :
    
    x = seq_a[i]
    
    empty[x] +=1
    
    
print(empty)
```

cProfile result :

```
> python -m cProfile -s cumulative  test-002-patched-002.py 
{'M': 0, 'A': 0, 'G': 0, 'L': 0, 'V': 0, 'W': 0, 'T': 0}
{'M': 10000000, 'A': 10000000, 'G': 10000000, 'L': 10000000, 'V': 10000000, 'W': 10000000, 'T': 10000000}
         140037786 function calls (140037745 primitive calls) in 84.476 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      6/1    0.000    0.000   84.476   84.476 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1   46.689   46.689   84.476   84.476 test-002-patched-002.py:3(<module>)
 70000000   28.766    0.000   37.673    0.000 test-002-patched-002.py:25(modded)
 70000000    8.907    0.000    8.907    0.000 {built-in method builtins.chr}

.........
.......
......
.....
...
```

Not sure is the right way to proceed , and if 20% faster is real (didnt try it a lot).  Just let me know

Cant slice `Seq` object anymore , unless you patch method back

Comment: Why the -1 ????